# Directive seems doesn't imported

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-module

I think directive is not working. I want a create a tooltip so I create directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[tooltip]',
  })
  export class TooltipDirective {
    @Input()
    public title: string;

 @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event'])
    public onMouseOver($event: MouseEvent): void {
console.log("HOME") // it doesn't print so I think the directive is not imported
}
}
```

My `tooltip.module.ts` is

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [TooltipComponent, TooltipDirective],
  exports: [TooltipDirective]
})
export class TooltipModule { }
```

Now when I want use the module I do in `home.module.ts`

```
 imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
      TooltipModule

    ],
```

and in my home.html code I do:

```
<i class="pi pi-question-circle" tooltip tooltipPosition="left" title="This is patrick"></i>
```

The problem is that directive is not working because it doesn't print ( console.log("HOME")) when I do mouse hove on . Anyone can help me?

Comment: `console.log` gets displayed in your console, not in your generated HTML. Are you sure it does not show any message in the console? What about errors?

Comment: Your code is correct. Three things I can come up with that could have happened. You have two directives (maybe a third party one) that uses the same selector `[tooltip]`. Or the `mouseover` event is being prevented from bubbling up by using `stopPropagation`. Or you need to restart `ng serve`, because you are using an old angular cli version which had a bug when you just created a new module

Comment: @PhilippMeissner yes sure!

Comment: @PoulKruijt I don't have antoher selector tooltip but only ptooltip because use primeng but I THINK there aren't problem

Comment: try: a)rename tooltip by some like customTooltip, b)add an input to get the variable tooltipPosition,c)put the "console.log("home") in constructor of the directive and tell us

Comment: @eliseo nothing . I follow this tutorial: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-tooltip-3232-3rydm7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Fdirectives%2Ftooltip.directive.ts

Comment: I put you suggest but it doesn't work!